# PYTHON get the last item of a list even if empty

Tags: python, multithreading, list, get, append

My Python script opens 2 `threading.Threads()` with the following functions :

1. `Stuff()` : function appending stuff to a `list` (global var) if stuff happens in a big loop.
2. `Monitor()` : function displaying the last item added to the `list` every second with additional info.

The purpose of these 2 threads is that `Stuff()` contains a loop optimized to be very fast (~ 200 ms / iteration) so printing from inside would be pointless. `Monitor()`takes care of the output instead.

At the beginning, I set `list = []`, then start the threads. Inside `Monitor()` I get the last item of the list with `list[-1]` but if no stuff happend before, the list is still empty and the `Monitor()` raises an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Is there a simple way (no `try` or `if not list`) to display `None` instead of an error if the list is empty ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a way, although it looks odd:

`(list or [None])[-1]`

Comment: For printing purposes, it will do the job. Thanks !

Comment: Note: the order is very important: if you do `([None] or list)[-1]` it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I find this more readable than @Alex's answer

```
lst = [1, 3, 2]
print None if not lst else lst[-1]
```

**Edit:** Though must admit, it is the first time I encountered that usage. Always thought those expressions returned bool type :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it also like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4][-1:] -> [4]
[][-1:]           -> []
[][-1:] or None   -> None
```